# Local Storage, Show and hide elements across different html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, show-hide

I have two html pages in my web app, index.html and topics.html.  i have a button in topics.html that when clicked, is supposed to make visible a hidden a Div in index.html so that when I navigate to index.html, the Div must be visible. I understand this can be achieved by local storage and windows.onload, how can I incorporate it to my code which looks like this

topics.html

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".me").show();
  });
});
```

On clicking the #show button, I want the Div below which is currently hidden to become visible like this so that when i navigate to index.html, the div is visible, and when i click the #hide button, it should stay hiddedn even when page reloads

Index.html (edited)

```
<div id="rss-feeds" class="me"></div>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
   $(".me").hide();
 });
});
```

How can i use local storage for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy if you name your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function showIt(){
    localStorage.shown=1;
    $(".me").show();
  }

  if(localStorage.shown==='1'){ showIt(); }
  $("#show").click(showIt);

});
```

that way you can call the same routine from the click event and during bootup from localStorage.

Comment: thank you. as soon as i tried to test you code i noticed that i needed to put a #hide button on the div that has to persist o reload, i then used the code for the hid button as well, the only problem is that it's not persisting when i reload the page so i can't test the code. please look at the edit I made on the original post. Thank you again @dandavis

Comment: i'll have to get back you later tonight, but it seems you can just adjust the css selectors in my answer and change show to hide...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way using this wonderful example and it works beautifully for anyone who might be interested.

https://gist.github.com/jakebresnehan/1983968

```
<button id="hide-button">Hide</button>
<button id="show-button">Show</button>

<div id="sign-up-form">
<p>Sign up form</p>
</div>

$(document).ready(function($){

if (Modernizr.localstorage) {

 $('#hide-button').click(function(e){
localStorage.setItem('subscribed',true);
  $('#sign-up-form,#hide-button').hide();
  $('#hide-button').hide();
  $('#show-button').show();
});

$('#show-button').click(function(e){
  localStorage.setItem('subscribed',true);
  localStorage.clear();
  $('#sign-up-form,#hide-button').show();
  $('#show-button').hide();
});

var is_subscribed = localStorage.getItem('subscribed');

if(is_subscribed){
console.log('localStorage')
$('#sign-up-form,#hide-button').hide();
}

if(!is_subscribed){
console.log('no localStorage');
$('#sign-up-form').show();
$('#show-button').hide();
}

 } 

 });
```